# Remove/revoke access of GitHub Organization's team to a repo using a command line

Tags: git, shell, github

I have a large number of teams in GitHub organization, and I need to give/remove access to certain repos. Further, I do not want to do it via GitHub web interface manually, but rather using the command line. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Github API, for organizations here is the documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/

Comment: No. This API endpoint manages membership at the org level while initial question was for repository level membership.